# How to solve html new line issue?

Tags: html

There is a specified html page which does not have `<p>` or even break line tags. A statement is displayed like below:

ThisIsABeautifulWorld!

But when we view the source by right clicking this is shown:

This 
Is 
A 
Beautiful 
World!

The question is is there any way to view the page like the source on working html page at all any without manual work?

Comment: Post some code please?

Comment: *«is there any way to view the page like the source on working html page at all any without manual work?»* - I **REALLY** don't get the question here. Hew what??

Comment: By the way, normally the source you gave, with the line breaks, normally would not end up looking like that, with no spaces whatsoever. So make sure there's no tricky css or even JavaScript involved that may disrupt things when you add a `pre` element.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking something like the [`<pre></pre>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) tag:

```
<pre>
This 
Is 
A 
Beautiful 
World!
</pre>
```

You can, alternatively, put some breaks `<br/>` at the end of each line.